# Build failed after remove Testflight

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, testflight

I'm a noob in the ios development. I've a project, which I need to remove from it, the testflight library. I have been commenting all referencing lines about Testflight, but now I've got the next error to a "_TFLog", but I don't know how to solve it.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_TFLog", referenced from:
      -[BibliotecaViewController loadCategories] in BibliotecaViewController-49994DBCE4C92E5B.o
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController checkUpdatesLocally] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController request:didFailWithError:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController completedPurchaseTransaction:] in ViewController.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What I need to do?

P.D.: Sorry for my english and Thank YOU!

Comment: Search for `TFLog` in code and comment/remove those lines.

Comment: Thanks, I had already noticed. In my project *-Prefix.pch, I had remove the next line:

#define NSLog(__FORMAT__, ...) TFLog((@"%s [Line %d] " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

Comment: so @lupatus way didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake when you import a header but don't link to the library.

You usually solve it by adding the library in the `build phases`->`link Binary with Library`'s section or the `build settings`->`Search Paths`->`Library Search Paths` 's section

But in your case, you don't wan't to use `TFLog`. So first search for `TFLog` in the whole projet (`cmd+shift+F`) and remove the concerned lines and try to rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

In the project, inside the file ***-Prefix.pch**, you need to remove the next line:

```
#define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) TFLog((@"%s [Line %d] " FORMAT), PRETTY_FUNCTION, LINE, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```